# Line-wise input, EOF handling, and behavioral differences between implementations of getchar

Tags: c, console, portability

I've implemented a menu system where all input calls ultimately go through `io_getline`, a function which reads a line of input up to the max buffer size or newline (the rest of the line is discarded if it exceeds the buffer size) and returns the number of characters written, or -1 if an EOF is encountered. When an EOF is encountered, io_getline will, from then on, permanently be in a state where the first character it attempts to read yields EOF (which is not a character) and it will always return -1. This is intentional, as I will soon demonstrate:

```
/* Does the same thing as getchar but with guaranteed EOF persistence */
static int
getchar_eof(void)
{
    unsigned char ch;
    static int eof_encountered;

    if(eof_encountered)
        return EOF;

    fread(&ch, 1, 1, stdin);

    if(feof(stdin)){
        eof_encountered = 1;
        return EOF;
    }

    return ch;
}

ssize_t
io_getline(char *buffer, size_t bufsz)
{
    int ch;
    char *bufp = buffer;

    while((ch = getchar_eof()) != EOF && ch != '\n')
        if(buffer != NULL && (size_t)(bufp - buffer) < bufsz)
            *bufp++ = ch;

    if(ch == EOF)
        return -1;

    return bufp - buffer;
}

/* two functions that use io_getline: */

int
generic_getter_str(struct menu_page *unused)
{
    (void)unused;
    ssize_t nwritten;

    showprompt();

    if((nwritten = io_getline(menustate.input_str, 32)) == -1)
        return CBRET_EOF; // causes caller to end the program

    if(nwritten == 0)
        return CBRET_RETURNTOPARENT;

    return CBRET_DONOTHING;
}

void
waitcontinue(void)
{
    printf("Press Enter to continue.");
    io_getline(NULL, 0);
    io_clearscreen();
}
```

A little bit about the menu structure: each page has three callbacks that are called in order: entry, getter and handler. The entry's job is to do anything that needs to be done before getting user input, the getter's job is to get input (`str`, `u32`, `char_or_u32`, and `none`) from the user, and handle EOF by ending the program, and the handler's job is to interpret the input obtained by the getter (if any). `waitcontinue` is called in some handler functions for the purpose of pagination, while `generic_getter_str` is one of the four getter functions.

As `waitcontinue` is not a getter, it does not handle EOF, but EOF will cause it to finish (this is expected). And this design decision is where I thankfully discovered a weird nuance with `getchar`, wherein it doesn't always persist EOF status. It is possible for getchar to return EOF, be called again, and *prompt the user for input post-EOF*. I managed to produce this behavior on both a repl.it Linux VM (repl.it/languages/c, without being logged in) and minGW on Windows (where I discovered it).

This goes against my understanding that getchar should constantly return EOF after the first time. The result of this is that any time `waitcontinue` is called in an environment where getchar behaves in this way, pressing `ctrl-d` (or `ctrl-z enter` if on Windows), the program will receive the EOF, skip the one waitcontinue call, and then continue to run, when the intent is for it to "bubble out" until a getter inevitably receives the EOF and ends the program.

This led me to re-implement getchar to guarantee the behavior that I want and expect, and it works fantastically, however, this is fascinating to me, and I now wonder if there are other nuances I might be missing here.

Comment: The project this is from is [mpassw](https://gitlab.com/bradenbest/mpassw/). A Metroid password generator I've been writing for the past couple weeks. It works on both Linux and Windows (MinGW). I have not tested it with a more windows-y compiler like MSVC, nor have I tested it on Mac. But I have no reason to believe it wouldn't work just fine on OS X.

Comment: Terminology problem: "_first character it reads is EOF_" - but `EOF` is **not a character**.  I'm not merely being pedantic here, because that's the thinking that leads to `char c = getchar()`, for example, or the idea that EOF is a single "thing" that can be consumed (or "received").

Comment: True, I was burned by `char c = getchar()` some years ago, which was how I learned that you really do need an `int`, as EOF is defined in terms of `int` and is out of range for even `unsigned char`. Poor wording on my part. I'd edit the question to mention what the manpage says, but I see an earlier post on my profile mentioning that apparently there's a rule against that. I imagine the rule is about preserving the code as it was first posted so that the answers make sense, but now that you've mentioned the terminology, I'm not sure if it's appropriate to change it.

Comment: I'll go ahead and make the edit since 1. it's not a code change and 2. the onus is a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Yes, editing to improve the prose to make it clearer, etc, is encouraged, even when you have answers.  It's just code changes we have to be more careful with, because that can make the answers seem nonsensical.  So you did the right thing.  :)

Comment: I don't have a review because I don't know how to trigger the transient EOF thing you describe - are you using `freopen()` or `fseek()` to clear the EOF in between calls?  Or are you reading from a regular file which is getting appended to (perhaps outside this process)?

Comment: @TobySpeight In my testing on MinGW on Windows, when stdin is coming from a user, and they send an EOF, and then getchar is called again after that, the terminal will prompt the user again for input. On my linux machine with stock gcc+glibc, sending one EOF is sufficient to make all future calls to getchar immediately return EOF until the program ends. You can send an EOF on a windows cmd terminal with `ctrl+z` followed by `enter`, whereas on a linux shell like bash, this is done with `ctrl+d`

Comment: You could try invoking it directly from my program by just changing the call to `getchar_eof` to `getchar` in `io.c`, and then modifying the makefile as necessary. Then just enter the detailed summary menu and send an EOF. As per my tests, with glibc, it should immediately exit, and with mingw, it should eat the EOF and continue running, exhibiting the (what I consider to be a) bug.

Comment: "I thankfully discovered a weird nuance with getchar, wherein it doesn't always persist EOF status." --> this is either non-conforming C behavior or a false positive.

Comment: `getchar()` can return `EOF` and then non-`EOF` due to input error in the first character and not the 2nd, yet this is rare.  @BradenBest What do you want `int getchar_eof(void)` to do in this case?

Comment: I was going to answer "return EOF", but since feof() always works even when a non-compliant getchar misbehaves, I was able to remove getchar_eof. That said, the way I've done it is io_getline will now return separate values for EOF and error in case I decide I want to handle errors differently in the future, but for now, the functions that call io_getline treat both EOF and error as an EOF

Answer (score 3):

**Redundant code**

`getchar_eof()` essentially mimics `getchar()` and `feof()`.  It fails to work well when `ferror()` is true or `stdin` is re-opened.

`getchar()` already returns `EOF` when `stdin` end-of-file flag is set.

Instead use, `getchar()`, `feof()`, `ferror()`.

**Bug**

`int getchar_eof(void)` returns junk (indeterminant data) when a rare input error encountered as the return value of `fread()` was not used.

**Bug**

`io_getline()` returns -1 when end-of-file occurs, even if some data was read.  To be like `fgets()`, only return -1 when 1) end-of-file occurs and nothing read or 2) input error.

**Non-portable type**

`ssize_t` is not defined in standard C.

**`generic_getter_str()` misnamed**

`generic_getter_str()` does not get a *string* (hinted by the `_str`) as no *null character* terminated array is gotten.

`io_getline(buffer, ...)` does not form a *string* in `buffer` as it lacks a *null character*.

**Repetitive test**

`if(buffer != NULL && (size_t)(bufp - buffer) < bufsz)` repeated tests `buffer != NULL`.  Once is enough.

```
if(buffer != NULL) bufsz == 0;  // Test once
while((ch = getchar_eof()) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    if((size_t)(bufp - buffer) < bufsz)
        *bufp++ = ch;
```

---

Candidate alternative - untested.

```
int io_getline(size_t bufsz, char buffer[bufsz]) {
  if (bufsz > INT_MAX) {
    bufsz = INT_MAX;  // Or some other error handling
  }
  if (buffer == NULL) {
    bufsz = 0;
  }

  int ch;
  char *bufp = buffer;
  bool data_read = false;

  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    data_read = true;
    if (ch == '\n') {
      break;
    }
    if ((size_t) (bufp - buffer) + 1u < bufsz) {
      *bufp++ = (char) ch;
    }
  }

  if (ch == EOF) {
    if (feof(stdin)) {
      if (!data_read) {
        return -1;
      }
    } else {
      return -1; // Input error
    }
  }

  if ((size_t) (bufp - buffer) < bufsz) {
    *bufp = '\0';  // Form a string if able
  }

  return (int) (bufp - buffer);
}
```

Comment: "io_getline() returns -1 when end-of-file occurs, even if some data was read." this is actually not a bug. The input is expected to come from a buffered commandline, i.e. a user types a line of input and terminates it by hitting enter. A line terminated by EOF is not a valid line, so it is discarded, just like excess input beyond the buffer size.

Comment: And `generic_getter_str` is not misnamed. Just because it's not a null-terminated string doesn't make it not a string. The function used to be named `generic_getter_char`, but after the introduction of `generic_getter_char_or_u32`, (single char or u32), it no longer made sense to keep it named `char`. I suppose I could name it `_charvec`. That said, in the wider context of the program, I make a point to avoid using null-terminated strings as data structures, and thus avoid `str*` lib functions in favor of their `mem*` counterparts.

Comment: The only string functions that appear in the program are used with string literals, and when a string function has to interact with one of my buffers, an intermediary buffer is used to keep their behavior under control (there is only one such case)

Comment: @BradenBest "I make a point to avoid using null-terminated strings" --> C does not specify any context where a _string_ is not null character terminated.  C lib does define "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  Of course you can use _string_ in some other context, but then that risks misunderstanding with the spec. and with users as evidenced by these comments.

Comment: @BradenBest "The input is expected to come from a buffered commandline, i.e. a user types a line of input and terminates it by hitting enter." --> OK, define it as you wish, yet it still differs from `fgets()`, a function commonly used to get lines and does serve as a model for many get line like code.  IIRC,  *nix `getine()` also does not discard a last line lacking a `'\n'`.

Comment: Regarding `ssize_t` and `getchar_eof`: I wasn't aware the type was POSIX-exclusive. I've opted instead to use `size_t` and define an absolute maximum line size for my program (4KiB). The EOF signal, which is returned on feof and ferror, is no longer `-1`, but it is a value outside of the range `0..IO_GETLINE_MAX`. I will also be getting rid of `getchar_eof`, as I have confirmed through testing that `feof()` returns correctly even when a non-conformant getchar is misbehaving.

Comment: `size_t` may seem overkill for 4KiB, but in my opinion, `size_t` is clearer about its purpose here than e.g. `uint16_t` or `int`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Chux. I've implemented all of your notes except for bug #2 which I do not see as a bug (`io_getline` is not meant to act exactly like `fgets`, otherwise I'd just use/wrap fgets). Instead, I have added "why" comments at the head of the function to document why the behavior is correct. I've +1'd your answer and named you in the contributors file. [Here's the commit](https://gitlab.com/bradenbest/mpassw/-/commit/2ed7acca55627ad5269b7ea8816eb6f334659a93).

Comment: @BradenBest Re `size_t` too big: Yes, for this `size_t` is indeed large (note may only be 65535), but if a smaller type was used, warnings may fire when call this code with a variable of type `size_t`.